# Can't apply simple 1 dimensional pooling in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to apply 1 dimensional pooling ti reduce the size of my input embeddings to a standard size.

I am trying:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(n_vocab,600)) embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix), trainable=True))
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(SimpleRNN(300,return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')))
model.compile('rmsprop', 'categorical_crossentropy')
```

But I get the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,18,127] vs. [1,9,127]
```

How can I resolve the error, I just want the input to be pooled to half its original size.

Comment: Where does the 127 come from? Is that the size of your input? Because I don't see that number during the network construction.

Comment: @sietschie n, its not input, the dime distributed layer is doing that..i don't understand

Comment: @tstseby You have not specified `input_shape` argument for the first layer (i.e Embedding layer).